# c2059 'return' error, novice to programming, would anyone be able to take a look at this?

Tags: c++

I am extremely new to programming (my second week in) and I am trying to understand why when I start without debugging, I keep receiving this error message!

I only receive one error and it is the "c2059" 'return' error code.. It's not descriptive at all, so I have no idea what I did wrong.

I have a picture link available below through google drive to show my code. Any help offered is greatly appreciated!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5hXFZn11VsudXBXRlI3Vjg1OEU/view?usp=sharing

I am also fairly new to this site, if I am breaking any formal etiquette, please let me know as well..

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: In future, please post actual code and a description of the error rather than a link to a picture. As soon as the link stops working your question becomes meaningless for anyone looking at it in the future.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Ironically I knew a Jonathan Potter in High School.

Comment: Important note: Newlines have no meaning to the C++ compiler.  Well, in the preprocessor stage (where comments are also removed) they do, but not when it comes to actual *syntax*.  And yours was a syntax error.  An even more useful rule of thumb is that the cause of the error can be anywhere above where the compiler figured out it had a problem.  (It can't ever be below, because the compiler processes the file almost exclusively from top to bottom, unlike some other languages like C# or Java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some stray text (`endl/`) at the end of the second last line, which is causing a parsing error.

You also appear to have typed `return o;` (the letter "o") - as you don't have a variable called `o` this will also cause an error. I suspect you meant `return 0;` instead.

Comment: YES! IT WORKS! Thank you! I have been stuck on this for days now! Unable to figure out what was wrong.

Comment: My sincerest of thank yous. Truly. Like I said, I have been trying to figure this out for days and have been unable to figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: To be fair that is not the clearest error message to understand. I would have expected the compiler to complain about the variable o.

Comment: @drescherjm: I'm sure it would have if the stray "endl/" text hadn't been there.